# How can you restrict the access of one endpoint in a mule application?

Tags: mule, policy, mule-esb

Suppose you have two endpoints in a mule application and you want to restrict access of one endpoint to a particular client application and make only another endpoint available for access.How can you implement this?

Comment: Please provide more details. Do you mean two endpoints in the same API or two separate HTTP Listeners configurations?

Comment: Yes,I mean if you have two endpoints in same application, lets say one get method and another post. You want a particular client application to access get only not post.How can you restrict this.

Comment: I was really expecting an a) or b) answer rather than a yes/no. But I understand that you refer to the first option, two endpoints of the same API, probably implemented with APIKit with RAML. Please edit your question to provide further clarifications.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a custom policy to achieve the same. So far, there is no OOTB policy available for the same. The other thing you could do but is not as elegant a solution ( this is also applicable in case you are not using API manager aspect of the platform)  is making use of filter in the Mule application (Mule3) and validation module in Mule4 whereby if the incoming request (for a given resource/HTTP verb combination)  has a particular clientId you drop/filter that request while you let others go through..